# azure functions server (isolated-process): Invoking SignalR group functions from client

Tags: c#, azure-functions, signalr

I am trying to add a SignalR client to specific SignalR group on an azure functions server (isolated-process). The server side code that I am trying to invoke is the following:

```
[Function("SendToGroup")]
[SignalROutput(HubName = "serverless", ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureSignalRConnectionString")]
public static SignalRMessageAction SendToGroup([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    using var bodyReader = new StreamReader(req.Body);
    return new SignalRMessageAction("newMessage")
    {
        Arguments = new[] { bodyReader.ReadToEnd() },
        GroupName = "groupToSend"
    };
}
```

I have tried invoking the above from the client side in C# with the following code to no avail:

```
    HubConnection _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://localhost:7071/api").Build();

    Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () => await _connection.StartAsync());

    //  This does not work      
    await HubConnectionExtensions.InvokeAsync(_connection, "SendToGroup");
```

In my searches, I have not found a single C# client code sample that shows how to connect to and remove oneself from signalR hub groups.  I would *really* appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Can you invoke a simple broadcast message? And does your user receive that said message?

Comment: Hello PhobosFerro - sorry for the late reply.  Yes I was able to get all the fundamentals to work in my sample.  I have a separate broadcast function which broadcasts messages via SignalR so there is no issue with the fundamentals.  The issue is the ASP.NET client side syntax needed to invoke the group management server side functions is glaringly missing from microsofts documentation.

Comment: Why are you using `HttpTrigger` instead of `SignalRTrigger`? `HttpTrigger` is usually only used in the Negotiate function.